# Following up on reimbursement of business expenses

Tags: expenses, travel

My company will not issue a corporate card for business trips. After a recent business trip I put in a request for reimbursement of meal expenses in line with company policy. That was three months ago.

How can I bring this up with my company to be reimbursed for current expenses, and to prevent future expenses from taking so long?

Comment: Should reimburse: 1 month, so you can pay your CC bill.  Reality: 3 months isn't usual for large companies possibly requiring multiple levels of approval.  Maybe find out if you can expense the CreditCard interest for their delay, and just pay the minimum.

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]! I think this has the core of a great question, but as-is it's collecting a few close votes. I'm going to give it an [edit] to try to bring it in line with the [help/on-topic], but if you can improve it (or you think I messed something up), please feel free to make an [edit] of your own to fix it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations or agreements that are company-specific and don't have universally applicable answers.

Comment: You aid you submitted "in line with company policy.? So what is the policy regarding their reimbursement schedule? Some only cut checks one a week, other once a month. How long do they have to either process the request, or kick it back for more info?

Comment: What's the process for the expense - get it signed off by your manager, submit it to the finance department, wait for them to pay it with your next pay packet? Do you know how far down the process the hold up is? Is there a reason you're uncomfortable just asking for an update, and do you know this is common practice in your company and not just a someone-dropped-the-ball one-off?

Comment: I believe business expenses that have not been reimbursed are tax deductible in the US.  This won't solve your issue, but does provide some positive to your situation.

Answer (score 4):

You should simply contact the person (or people) who is responsible for travel and expense reimbursements and ask them if there is anything that **you** can do to assist in processing your expense report. That way you won't seem to be "bugging" them about the slowness of the process and they may be able to give you some advice on how to make future reimbursements go through the system faster.

Frankly, if travel and/or expense reimbursements DO become a long-term problem with this company, you might consider other employment options. If they are unwilling to issue employees corporate cards, yet they are equally unwilling to reimburse them promptly for expenses accrued during company business or travel. that may speak volumes on how concerned they are about their workforce.

Comment: I would add that if my employer refused to issue a company card to me and also refused to reimburse expenses I incurred at their request, I would refuse to incur more expenses (assuming I did not look for other employment).